# Formula to find the sum of difference b/w two numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have an array of 5 numbers [10,20,30,40,50]

I get the sum of difference b/w two numbers as

```
20-10 = 10
30-20 = 10
40-30 = 10
50-40 = 10
Total = 40
```

Is there a way to get this value 40 by other method
I tried by adding all the values in array and substracting n time the minimum value in array

```
10+20+30+40+50=150
150-(10*5) = 100
```

But I have to use only min, max, avg ... only sql functions

Comment: Telescope ? $a_n-a_1$ ?

Comment: Wow! will it works for all sizes of arrays say the array size is 100?

Comment: Why not ? If you are doing $\sum_{i=1}^n(a_{i}-a_{i-1})$

Comment: You are very welcome !